kcat connecting to a Kafka cluster setup with no authentication
I am trying to list topics on a Kafka cluster that is setup with no authentication. I am using the command line where b1 and b2 are broker names.
kcat -b b1:9094,b2:9094 -F kc.properties -L

My kc.properties is as shown below:
bootstrap.servers="b1:9094,b2:9094"
security.protocol=PLAINTEXT

I have tried without adding the "security.protocol" line as well.
However, I am getting the following error message:
Disconnected while requesting ApiVersion: might be caused by incorrect security.protocol configuration (connecting to a SSL listener?) or broker version is < 0.10 (see api.version.request) (after 38ms in state APIVERSION_QUERY

Brokers are on AWS MSK version 2.2.1

Port 9094 isn't plaintext https://docs.aws.amazon.com/msk/latest/developerguide/port-info.html

I  tried kcat -b b1:9094,b2:9094 -F kc.properties -L with the  following in kc.properties bootstrap.servers="b1:9092,b2:9092"
security.protocol=PLAINTEXT. This did not work

When you provide -b then it probably overrides the property file bootstrap servers, so port 9094 would still be used... You should not need both

I was able to connect by setting the  security.protocol to SSL as in:
bootstrap.servers="b1:9094,b2:9094"
security.protocol=SSL

